# Is there a way to prefill quantity on a payment link via URL parameters?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm looking to prefill the quantity on a payment link via URL parameters.

I've looked through documentation but haven't found a way to do it. Is this possible currently or a planned addition to payment links?

URL parameter docs: https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customer-info#customize-checkout-with-url-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available query parameters are listed on the page you [linked to](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customer-info#customize-checkout-with-url-parameters).  Quantity is not one of them and can only be updated through the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/payment-links) or the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/update#update_payment_link-line_items-quantity).

Comment: Got it. I think I'm going to create individual payment links instead which allows you to set a quantity beforehand. It would be nice if this was a feature though that way you don't have to manage multiple payment links.

Comment: I suspect exposing `quantity` as a URL parameter would be a security issue.  A malicious actor could modify the URL on your website to force customers to purchase 10000 of whatever you are selling.